# HTML5 Thymeleaf - placeholder for input type=number shows 0

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm creating a simple HTML form along with Thymelaf that I use in my Spring Boot application.

 
 In the form I specified a following statement:

```html
<input type="number" step="0.1" min="0" max="10" **th:field="*{rating}"**
                   class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Rating">
```

However, instead of *Rating*, the value showed in the form is *0*.

[image: outcome]

Once you delete the 0, placeholder finally appears.

[image: desired_outcome]

***Edit***
Apparently, Thymeleaf seems to cause the problem here.

```
<input type="number" step="0.1" min="0" max="10" th:field="*{rating}"
                   class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Rating">
<input type="number" placeholder="Test Rating"
                   class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
```

The form without ***th:field="*{rating}"*** works fine. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the default of 0 you can't use primitive data types as `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`.

Instead use wrapper class with `null` for a variable related with `th:field="*{rating}"` for empty form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected in plain HTML. Try using `th:placeholder` attribute instead of `placeholder`

Comment: You're right - I forgot to mention I'm using Thymeleaf. However, the issue still persists with th:placeholder.